# How to get a list of uploaded custom-background images in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, background-image

I'm building a theme and I'd like to use the 'supersized' script to rotate the background images. 
I've used the WP built-in customizer to upload a couple of background images. They show up in the customizer under the "Background Image"->"Uploaded" tab.

What I am looking for is **the code to retrieve the urls of those images** - just as it is done in customizer, but I would use it in my script.

I looked through the 'customize.php' in /wp-admin/ but it only invokes some function and the code for this function is elsewhere. Anyone has some knowledge on where this code is located?

Interestingly, the images uploaded through customizer do not show up in media library...

Anyone could help with that?

EDIT: In other words - **what is the query that would return urls of custom-background images uploaded through the customizer?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! I've searched the entire WP database for the IDs of the images that are custom-background. Turns out they have a special key in 'post_meta' table: '_wp_attachment_is_custom_background'

Using this key in WP_query I was able to find exactly the images uploaded as custom backgrounds through the customizer.

For everyone's benefit, here is the code I used in my 'header.php':

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        $.supersized({
            // Functionality
            slide_interval    : 5000,
            transition        : 1, 
            transition_speed  : 2000,               
            slide_links       : 'blank',
            slides            : [
<?php 
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 
               'post_mime_type' =>'image', 
               'post_status' => 'inherit',
               'meta_query' => array (
                  array (
                    'key' => '_wp_attachment_is_custom_background',
),) ); 
$bk_images = new WP_Query( $args ); 
$in = 0; 
$in_end = sizeof($bk_images->posts);
foreach ( $bk_images->posts as $bk) { 
    $in++;
    echo "   {image : '" . wp_get_attachment_url( $bk->ID ) . "', title : 'Title', url : 'url'}"; 
    if ($in<$in_end) { echo ",\n"; } else { echo "\n"; }
} ?>
                                 ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if is a static page you can try with this addon for acf plugin [repeater field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/repeater-field/)

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <?php if(get_field('carrusel')):?>
            <?php while(has_sub_field('carrusel')): ?>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="<?php $image = get_sub_field('image'); echo $image; ?>" alt="Slide">
        </div>
            <?php endwhile ?>
        <?php endif ?>
    </div>
    <a id="nav-izq" class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <img src="<?php PRINT IMAGES ?>/nav-izq.png" alt="">
    </a>
    <a id="nav-der" class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <img src="<?php PRINT IMAGES ?>/nav-der.png" alt="">
    </a>
</div>
```

this is a example of bootstrap carousel created with acf repeater field

Comment: If I wanted to take it easy, I could've used the 'WP Supersized' plugin. I'm trying to do this without any plugins - the hard way...

Comment: i added my bootstrap carousel for test the plugin, you can use bootstrap carousel with full width & height

Comment: Siddharta, this may be a work-around, although I'm trying to solve this without using custom fields. The images are already uploaded in WP, and stored somewhere in the DB. I just need a proper query to find them.

Comment: $query_images_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' =>'image', 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'posts_per_page' => -1,
);

$query_images = new WP_Query( $query_images_args );
$images = array();
foreach ( $query_images->posts as $image) {
    $images[]= wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID );
}

Comment: Siddharta, this returns the urls of ALL images. I need only the images uploaded through the customizer as custom-background.